# How do you get "CL.exe" if MSBuild must be installed via command line?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, msbuild

I'm trying to build a deployment container for my project which depends on `CL.exe`, which is part of the MSVC package. Therefore, I must install the compiler via command line. Right now, I'm installing MSBuild 16 like this:

```
RUN ./vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --norestart --nocache --wait \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools
```

But `CL.exe` is not found anywhere. How do I fix this command so that MSBuild installs the MSVC package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64` will install MSVC, including `CL.exe`:

```
RUN ./vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --norestart --nocache --wait \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools \
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
```

If you look at ["Visual Studio Build Tools component directory"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019#c-build-tools), MSVC is listed as a "Recommended" dependency type. Only "Required" components of get added for a given workload, so you must either use the flag [`--includeRecommended` or `--includeOptional`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), or append specific components that are not labeled as required.

To check if it worked:

```
RUN Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio' -Filter CL.exe -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

```
    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
    Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\Hostx64\x64


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                          
-a----         6/2/2019  10:50 AM         430216 cl.exe                        


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
    Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\Hostx64\x86


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                          
-a----         6/2/2019  10:50 AM         431760 cl.exe                        


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
    Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\Hostx86\x64


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                          
-a----         6/2/2019  10:50 AM         361096 cl.exe                        


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
    Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\Hostx86\x86


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                          
-a----         6/2/2019  10:50 AM         363152 cl.exe
```

Comment: How do you use the include-recommended/include-optional flag? I have seen it in many different ways, like `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools;includeOptional` and `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --include-optional` and it is never clear if it actually worked

Comment: @netpoetica The first one doesn't look correct so I believe it's the second one. There doesn't seem to be a way to list installed packages but if you're building a project after this, why not just build it and see if that succeeded?